# How to call a perl script from flex?

Tags: apache-flex, perl, air

is it possible to call a Perl script from flex?

I need to call Perl script from Flex user interface. 
I am working over application that copies large data files from one device to another.
User interface is created in Java Swing and it is calling Perl scripts.   But customer doesn't like user interface.
I have very nice user interface created in Flex AIR. 
Now I have to run Perl scripts from Flex and show user data loading progress.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: this may help you http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/978129#978129